# Hide a sharePoint subsite by name using Js

Tags: sharepoint-online, hide-elements

This is the code that get me and display all my subsite. The problem is I need Display all subsites instead of one that I need to hide "Test3" using javascript.

```
<html>
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetriveSites,"sp.js");

function RetriveSites()
{
    currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    currentweb = currentcontext.get_web();
    //this.subsites = currentweb.get_webs();
    this.subsites = currentweb.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
    currentcontext.load(this.subsites);
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnSuccess),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnFailure));
}
function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) {
    var subsites = '';
    var enum1 = this.subsites.getEnumerator();
    var el = document.getElementById('LKMSubWebs');
    while (enum1.moveNext())
    {
        var Site = enum1.get_current();
        //alert('hi123');
        subsites += '\n' + '<a class=subsitecls href='+ Site.get_serverRelativeUrl()+'>'+Site.get_title()+'</a> </br>'
        //RootElement.append('<a class=subsitecls href='+ siteTitle+'>'+siteTitle+'</a> </br>');
        //alert(subsites);
    }
    el.innerHTML = subsites;
}
function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) {
    alert("error");
    //alert(args.get_message());
}
</script>

<div id="LKMSubWebs"></div>
</html>
```

thank you

---

[image]

when I Edit the page
[image]
When I save it
That is very strange

Answer (score 3):

Within your enumeration, check for site's title and if it matches 'Test3' then use continue keyword to skip.

```
while (enum1.moveNext()) {
 var Site = enum1.get_current();
 var obj = {
    title: Site.get_title(),
    url: Site.get_serverRelativeUrl()
 };

 if (obj.title == 'Test3')
    continue;

 subsites += '\n' + '<a class="subsitecls" href=' + obj.url + '>' + obj.title + '</a> </br>'
}
```

FYI: To get sub-sub sites (multi-level deep), you'd need to use recursive function.

Comment: Thank you Aveenav. It's works but when I save the page, the subsite name "Test3" is still there.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your rendered html?

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code. I'm using a small Css code for the style.

```
      <script>
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetriveSites, "sp.js");

        function RetriveSites() {
            currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            currentweb = currentcontext.get_web();
            //this.subsites = currentweb.get_webs();
            this.subsites = currentweb.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
            currentcontext.load(this.subsites);
            currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnSuccess),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnFailure));
        }
        function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var subsites = '';
            var enum1 = this.subsites.getEnumerator();
            var el = document.getElementById('LKMSubWebs');
            while (enum1.moveNext()) {
                var Site = enum1.get_current();
                 var obj = {  title: Site.get_title(),
                   url: Site.get_serverRelativeUrl()};
     if (obj.title == 'Test3' )
    continue;
    if (obj.title=='Test1')
   continue;
   //alert('hi123');

subsites += '\n' + '<div class="alpha"> <a class=subsitecls            href=' + Site.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '>' + Site.get_title() + '</a>     </br></div>'

                //RootElement.append('<a class=subsitecls href='+    siteTitle+'>'+siteTitle+'</a> </br>');
                //alert(subsites);
            }
            el.innerHTML = subsites;

            if (Site.get_title() = "Test3")
            {
                document.getElementByName("Test3").style.display = 'none';
            }

        }

        function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) {
            alert("error");
            //alert(args.get_message());
        }
    </script>
    <div id="LKMSubWebs"></div>
```